# unexpected black box at the left top corner of a table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have tried to implement compact table that has different row colors (gray and white). I have following piece of code that puts unexpected black box at the left top corner on the seconds table, I believe this is always put to latest table on the document:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}
\newlist{legal}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[legal]{label*=\arabic*.}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill// #1}
\makeatletter
\def\algbackskip{\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
        \toprule\addlinespace[0pt]
        \textbf{Method} & \textbf{Used Value} \\
        \toprule\addlinespace[0pt] \rowcolor{gray!25}
        $func1()$       & 1000                \\ \rowcolor{gray!25}
        $func2()$       & 1000                \\
        $func3()$       & 1000                \\ \rowcolor{gray!25}
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{}\label{tab:tests}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        \addlinespace[0pt]
        \textbf{Providers} & \textbf{No} & \textbf{Number} \\
        \toprule\addlinespace[0pt] \rowcolor{gray!25}
        $user\_1$          & 100         & 4               \\
        $user\_2$          & 100         & 4               \\
        $user\_3$          & 100         & 4               \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here interestingly there is a black box show up at the [0,0] grid of the table:

[image]
What might be the reason of this error, how can I fix it?

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What's the purpose of `\addlinespace[0pt]`?

Comment: Ah I believe it removes extra space at the top in between the top line and the string below.

Comment: What is that ``\\ \rowcolor{gray!25}`` at the end of the first table suppose to do? Color the rule below it. Everything is normal for me if I remove it.

Comment: `\noalign{\normalsize}` ???

Comment: @daleif I have updated my question in original work I was using multiple lines. I was just aiming to have odd number rows to be gray and even number of rows to be white. I was able to make it work by adding `\rowcolor{gray!25}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added `\noalign{\normalsize}` very long time ago, I believe I used it to make the table more compact. I tried to adapt it from solutions I may used it in a wrong location

Comment: No it does absolutely nothing, it is like using `{\normalsize}`  outside table, it selects a font that is never used as the group immdiately ends and reverts the setting

Comment: @daleif I believe having `\rowcolor{gray!25}` in wrong order causing this

Comment: You are passing `\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}` so can specify the zebra striped ables as a global declaration you do no have to use `\rowcolor` every other line.

Comment: I was hoping to achieve what you mentioned, but when I don't use a `\rowcolor` it does not apply gray color at all :-( Only way I achived it was to write `\rowcolor` every other line

Comment: `\rowcolor` comes from `colortbl` `xcolor` provides the extension `\rowcolors` (with an s)  `\rowcolors{}{gray!25}` before the table

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Having `rowcolors{1}{}{gray!25}` before the tabular help me to solve the zebra stripes and the unexpected black box. I am not sure but `\rowcolors{}{gray!25}` did not work did not apply any color @DavidCarlisle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is identified and solve by @daleif comment, however your table is simpler to write by use of the `tabularray` package (at least to my opinion). Using it, coloring of rows is simple and without gaps between color strips and table rules determined by `booktabs` package (loaded as `tabularray` library).

Tables in the left column have first column in math mode ()I wonder why you select this), and in the second row in the text mode as are other rows in table.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
First column is in math mode:
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l, mode=math] c},
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
                 row{even} = {gray9}
                 }
    \toprule
Method  &   Used Value      \\
    \midrule
func1() & 1000              \\ 
func2() & 1000              \\
func3() & 1000              \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:tests}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l, mode=math] c c},
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries, mode=text},
                 row{even} = {gray9}
                 }
    \toprule
Providers   &   N   &   Number  \\
    \midrule
user\_1     & 100   & 4         \\
user\_2     & 100   & 4         \\
user\_3     & 100   & 4         \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\newpage
First column is in text mode as others columns:
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l] c},
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                 row{even} = {gray9}
                 }
    \toprule
Method  &   Used Value      \\
    \midrule
func1() & 1000              \\
func2() & 1000              \\
func3() & 1000              \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:tests}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={Q[l] c c},
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                 row{even} = {gray9}
                 }
    \toprule
Providers   &   N   &   Number  \\
    \midrule
user\_1     & 100   & 4         \\
user\_2     & 100   & 4         \\
user\_3     & 100   & 4         \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I have a long string in on of the top row column somehing like `Number of completed task` instead of `N` could it be splitted like `Number of` (newline) `completed task` ; because when I add `&   of completed   &    \\ ` the coloring get started from the top second row

Comment: @alper, in answer I consider only what is in your question. If you have new problem, please ask new question. Sorry, but I can't figured out what you try to explain me in comment.

Comment: The reason I selected `math-mode` in the first column is that, it seems more compact where there was less space in between the characters and characters seems little bit bolder than normal text mode. But I am not sure is it the right approach to do it

Comment: Please see the example figure: https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/aa8d52e2748316e20e744f97568487be?permalink_comment_id=4137543#gistcomment-4137543 like if I split top rule into multiple lines I want coloring to start from 3. row since first 2 is allocated for the main row title

Comment: @alper, sorry, you are wrong (i) text in math mode is not more compact; (ii) in math mode are written only variables.

Comment: @alper, please edit your question and add missed information (at least). Your link can become after while dead and people will not see anymore what is your problem.

Comment: In the text mode (on your first drawn figur) could the text on the first be `non-italic`? I think I wanted to prevent that as well using math-mode

Comment: I will ask new question if I cannot figure it out having multiple line for the title row but your answer solves what I was looking for thank you.